# How to guarantee 2 digit month in Java without using formatting string literals?

Tags: java, datetime, formatting

I'm not sure if this will always issue a 2 digit month:

```
java.time.LocalDateTime ldt = java.time.LocalDateTime.now( java.time.ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ));

String path = "my/path/" + ldt.getYear().toString() + "/" + ldt.getMonthValue().toString() + "/" + ldt.getDayOfMonth().toString() + "/" + ldt.getHour().toString() + "/";
```

Now it does because we're in a two digit month. How to check if it will work for July, for example?

Cannot use "%02d" formatting.

Sorry, new to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Switching your ask to use standard ISO 8601 formatting…

```
"my/path/" +
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) 
) 
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH" ) 
)
.toString()
```

[When run](https://ideone.com/9vIHup):

> my/path/2020-11-17T21

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Let the [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class do your formatting work. No need for you to manipulate the string.

The double character such as `dd` rather than `d` forces a leading zero where needed. Carefully read the class Javadoc to understand the formatting codes.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/MM/dd/HH" ) ;
String s = ldt.format( f ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

Your slash character (SOLIDUS) can be interpreted as meaning a folder/directory. So I suggest you stick with standardized [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Standard format keeps the year-month-day-hour ordering, but uses HYPHEN characters as delimiters. And a `T` separates the time-of-day from the date portion.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify any formatting pattern.

And while you are at it, I would use minute as well, so the date and time are easily recognizable. If you want a zero minute consistently, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) to hour.

```
String s = ldt.truncatedTo( java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS ).toString() ;
```

Last issue: In some popular file systems, a COLON character may also be interpreted as a folder/directory. So we should avoid the COLON character between the hour and minute. See [this Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/160295/17907) at sibling site http://www.AskDifferent.com/ about strategies for this.

Or perhaps you want to stick with hour only and no minute.

Putting that all together:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH" ) ;

ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now( z ) ;
String s = ldt.format( f ) ;

String output =  "my/path/" + s ;
System.out.println( "output → " + output ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/9vIHup).

> output → my/path/2020-11-17T21

## `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment

By the way, do you understand that `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment? It purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. That type represents a date such as January 23rd, 2021, and a time-of-day such as noon, but we do not know if that means noon on the 23rd in Tokyo, noon on the 23rd in Paris, or noon on the 23rd in Montréal, three very different moments several hours apart. So your code `java.time.LocalDateTime.now( java.time.ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ))` may not be meeting your expectations.

To capture a moment, use `Instant` (always in UTC), `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks! So you're saying do this instead: java.time.ZonedDateTime.now( java.time.ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ))?

Comment: @Kenobi Yes, if you want to track a specific point on the timeline, use Instant/OffsetDateTime/ZonedDateTime. If you want to see the date and the time-of-day as it appeared to people in the region where they use the New York time zone, yes, use `ZonedDateTime.now( … )`. If you want that same moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds), use `Instant.now()`. Search Stack Overflow to learn more as this has been covered many many many many times already.

Comment: Yup, got it! Thank you very much Sir!